# If statement doesn't perform in my Python script?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def timeConversion(s):
z = s.split(':')
if 'p' in z[2]:
    print("Hello")
    z[0] = str(int(z[0]) + 12)
    z[2] = z[2][:-2]
    t = (':'.join(str(i) for i in z))
    return(t)
if 'a' in z[2]:
    z[2] = z[2][:-2]
    t = (':'.join(str(i) for i in z))
    return(t)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    d = timeConversion('07:05:45PM')
    print(d)

Comment: expected output = 19:05:45 got None

Comment: There is at least one answer to the real question below, but maybe you could just use https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime with `%I` and `%p`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def timeConversion(s):
    z = s.split(':')
    if 'P' in z[2]:
        print("Hello")
        z[0] = str(int(z[0]) + 12)
        z[2] = z[2][:-2]
        t = (':'.join(str(i) for i in z))
        return(t)
    if 'A' in z[2]:
        z[2] = z[2][:-2]
        t = (':'.join(str(i) for i in z))
        return(t)
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    d = timeConversion('07:05:45PM') 
    print(d)
```

Comment: 'P' and 'A' are in uppercase.